# Tomcat _localhost:port_ set globally for every system

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat7

I have *localhost:port* for webApplication. Can I declare it as globally? 
Like once I create .war I can use it any tomcat or any system, without changing it?

```
String url=http://localhost:8080/app/xyz.jsp
```

I want to declare *localhost:8080* as globally(when i hard coded it to my application),like user definable flag.

Thanx.

**I got it, I used *localhost* as *127.0.0.1* points self
And *port* address**

```
Server server = ServerFactory.getServer();
        Service[] services = server.findServices();
        for (Service service : services) {
            for (Connector connector : service.findConnectors()) {
                ProtocolHandler protocolHandler = connector
                        .getProtocolHandler();
                if (protocolHandler instanceof Http11Protocol
                        || protocolHandler instanceof Http11AprProtocol
                        || protocolHandler instanceof Http11NioProtocol) {
                    serverPort = String.valueOf(connector.getPort());
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanx for helping.

Comment: .war is your application specific and change of port no. is server specific. You deploy your war on any system or server instance, you have to change server port number as per your requirement or with your intent.

Comment: hello, if i need to add localhost:port hard coded for any jsp page in application,then how can i manage it?

Comment: user server path or server name and context path object of servlet request

Comment: Re your edit, you don't need any of that, as you've already been told. All the information you need is available via the HttpServletRequest.

Comment: @EJP am in RESTlet, and am in java class where using `http://127.0.0.1:" + serverPort+ "/app/xyz.jsp`
ll it work for all,
And i tried your answer in Servlet its working, i know, but may above is comfortable for me.

Comment: @Rocco Of course it works, but it is hardly 'comfortable'. You are using a container-specific API where you don't need to, and writing 13 lines of code where one will do.

Comment: yes, it is. i cant extend other because one is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not even desirable. You can get the information at runtime, e.g. via EL:

```
#{request.scheme}://#{request.serverName}:#{request.serverPort}/#{request.contextPath}/...
```

Then your applicaton can survive arbitrary rehosting, re-configuration of Tomcat, reassignment of ports, ... by other people. No action required at all.

Comment: can you please elaborate on what exactly is "EL"?

Comment: @Snake EL is an abbreviation for _Expression Language_. Read here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Comment: And actually there is no implicit _request_ object in EL. To access HttpServletRequest properties you should use **${pageContext.request.propertyName}** (or # instead of $), where _propertyName_ is one of the HttpServletRequest / ServletRequest properties. For instance: `${pageContext.request.scheme}`

Answer (score 0):

`I don't think so this is possible`.

Deployed war file belongs to `application` , `Hostname` and `port` belongs to server configuration which can be configured as per your requirement. You can configure them to run the application on `SSL` also.